# Adding a ChangeListener to hide progress indictor when the WebEngine has loaded

Tags: javafx

I am trying to use JavaFX to display a progress indicator while waiting for video to load.

I have been able to piece together the below code from reading other posts.

However I'm not sure why the progress indicator is not displaying?  The video takes 3-4secs to load, while the video is loading all I'm seeing is white box.

I have these two libraries imported.

import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener

import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

[image]

```
                HBox videoBox = new HBox();
                centerGridMain.add(videoBox, 6, 2);
                videoBox.setEffect(new DropShadow());

                ProgressIndicator pi = new ProgressIndicator();

                WebEngine webEngine = new WebEngine();
                WebView webView = new WebView();
                webEngine=webView.getEngine();
                webEngine.load("https://www.youtube.com/embed/ER8-WJxoItE");
                videoBox.getChildren().addAll(webView, pi);
                pi.progressProperty().bind(webEngine.getLoadWorker().progressProperty());
                
            
                webEngine.getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<State>() {

                    @Override
                    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends State> ov, State oldState, State newState) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        if (newState == State.SUCCEEDED) {
                            pi.setVisible(false);
                        }

                        else {
                            pi.setVisible(true);
                        }

                    }
                });
```

Comment: Create and post a [mre] please

Comment: Not sure if this is best practise, but I ended replacing
videoBox.getChildren().addAll(webView, pi); with  videoBox.getChildren().addAll(pi); 
and
pi.setVisible(false); with videoBox.getChildren().add(webView);
Which has the desired effect.

Comment: HBox is going to place nodes horizontally.  My guess is that the PI is over to the right, and out beyond the limits of your scene.  Try using a VBox, so the PI is below the WebView.

Comment: Thank  you @DaveB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing this and it had the desired result.

```
       HBox videoBox = new HBox();
        centerGridMain.add(videoBox, 6, 2);
        videoBox.setEffect(new DropShadow());

        ProgressIndicator pi = new ProgressIndicator();

        WebEngine webEngine = new WebEngine();
        WebView webView = new WebView();
        webEngine=webView.getEngine();
        webEngine.load("https://www.youtube.com/embed/ER8-WJxoItE");
        videoBox.getChildren().addAll(pi);
        pi.progressProperty().bind(webEngine.getLoadWorker().progressProperty());
        
    
        webEngine.getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<State>() {

            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends State> ov, State oldState, State newState) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (newState == State.SUCCEEDED) {
                    videoBox.getChildren().addAll(webView);;
                }

                else {
                    pi.setVisible(true);
                }

            }
        });
```